# How can I lock UI while running the long running process in the main UI Thread in WPF (code in C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, disabled-input, screen-lock

Actually, I cannot run the long running process in the Background thread. The long running process gets its input directly from the UI and then it has to save any modifications in the database. So, this long running process is unable to access the input in the background thread despite being written inside the Dispatch code(given below):

```
  this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
   {
       ...//The long running process inside background thread.
   }));
```

My basic is to prevent the user from clicking anywhere else while the long running process is running. So, is there any other way by which this can be done?

Comment: what if you don't use the dispatcher ... the ui thread would be locked rite?

Comment: How about you get all the data from UI to some data storage class - snapshot of that data at the moment of invocation and program your logic against that. You wont be needing UI any more and you could execute in thread. Your logic would return appropriate result and then in main thread you would simply display it. In meanwhile your UI will be responsive displaying say some progress bar. Its better then unresponsive app.

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad IF I don't use the dispatcher and write the long running process in the main UI thread, the screen would become unresponsive....

Comment: If you want to display some progress then Rafal answer is good ... else you can set the enable property of your buttons to false while the background thread is running to disable the controls and enable it later on.

Comment: Have your UI thread post appropriate input data to the LRP in the background thread, using a message queue or similar.  Better than trying to get the LRP to stop and check for input periodically.

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad I had tried that but the problem is that if you are working on a single thread(which in my case is the main UI thread) then all the events in that thread fires after the long running process is over.So, here the buttons were disabled after the process got over despite the fact that I had written the "buttonname.IsEnabled= false;" command at the beginning of the thread. Also, my initial plan was to show a "Please wait" screen. I am working on Rafal's suggestion. I Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

- Make a "global" (seen for UI thread and background thread) object of one of concurrent [types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx). You can make it as singleton or pass an object to both threads
- All the long running thread does is reading data from concurrent object and process them.
- If main thread (or any other) need to do anything in background simply adds it to the concurrent collection.

This kind of approach in concurrent programming is called [Producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)